# 2008 Mercury Mariner 3.0 Fuse #26 blowing intermittently

Tags: electrical, fuse, mercury, mariner

Looking at the owners manual fuse box diagram it's the PCM Mil but I suspect that there's more on that circuit.  Having an odd intermittent fuse blowing and it seems to be sitting at a light or even backing out of my driveway and then putting into drive or pulling from idle at a stop light it will blow and I lose the ability for the car to idle itself and the transmission slams into gear but that could be because i have to hold the RPM's above like 800-1000 to keep it running or it flat lines.  I'm assuming the IAC is on that circuit or MAF but when it blows the CEL only comes on about 50% of the time and then clears itself after about 30 or 40 key cycles if the fuse doesnt blow in between.

Any chance someone has access to the underhood fuse #26 circuit and could give me some pointers on what I can check?  Couldn't be a bad CEL bulb could it?